# Getting Null values from req.body

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, express

```
router.post("/Signup", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    db.query(
      'SELECT email FROM auth WHERE email ="' + req.body.email + '"',
      async (err, result) => {
        if (err) return err;
        if (result.length === 0) {
          const redirectUrl = req.session.returnTo || "/home";
          delete req.session.returnTo;
          // const salt =  bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
          // const hash =  bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.pass, salt);
          const users = {
            firstname: req.body.firstname,
            lastname: req.body.lastname,
            email: req.body.email,
            pass: req.body.p
            phone: req.body.phone,
            address: req.body.address,
            city: req.body.city,
            province: req.body.province,
            zip: req.body.zip,
            img: req.body.img
          };
          const sql = "INSERT INTO auth SET ?";
          await db.query(sql, [users], (err, rows) => {
            if (err) res.send(err);
            else req.flash("success", "Successfully registered!");
            return console.log('complete');
          });
        } else if (result[0].email.length > 0) {
          req.flash("error", "The Entered email already exsists");
          return res.redirect("/Signup");
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (e) {

    next(e);
  }
});
```

This is my post route for signup. but it is not geeting the value from req.body.I have also used bodyparser.It is showing this message.

[image: error]

If there something wrong with my code.PLease tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you are using JSON bodyparser, but you are sending your request as form-data. Make sure that you are using the same body type everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 concerns here.

1. check wether you are using bodyparser or not, if not using, please install and use as here.

`var bodyParser = require('body-parser')`
`var app = express()`

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`
`app.use(bodyParser.json())`

2. In the postman, below the **body** tab, click on **raw** and select type as **json**

and submit the request.

Hope this helps!